# Partial view - avoiding nested forms

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, partial-views

**View**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    ...form elements
    @Html.Action("PartialView")
}
```

**PartialView**

```
if (something) {
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
} else {
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    }
```

Can anybody suggest a way around the above problem?

If the PartialView if statement returns false, I end up with nested forms. I can move the form close bracket within the partial view to avoid nesting the forms and the page renders correctly but this upsets visual studio because it expects to see the close bracket within the view. Does that matter?

Edit:

Based on Chris's comments, is the below modification a better approach? i.e. One form with two submit buttons that call different code within the same action method?

**PartialView**

```
if (something) {
    <input type="submit" name="btn" value="Submit1" />
} else {
    <input type="submit" name="btn" value="Submit2" />
}
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    if (btn == "Submit1") {
        ...do a thing
    } else {
        ...do another thing
    };
}
```

Comment: Please `dont use <form> inside another <form>`

Comment: Thanks Murali. That's the problem. What's the solution?

Comment: Can you not design the partial view in a way where it does not have to have it's own `Html.BeginForm`?

Comment: Maybe I'll have to do that Chris. At the moment, each form calls a different action method. Maybe they should both call the same action method containing an if statement that returns true or false depending on which form made the call.

Comment: I would say that would be a better approach. In Web Forms, sub-forms are always a problem because the whole page is a form. It is very typical, as a result, to simply name the submit buttons for each "form". They're not really separate forms, but by giving the submit button a unique name, you can check for it's existence in the post data on the server-side and determine which "form" was posted by the user.

Comment: I would suggest you to use ajax call to submit child form into different action.

Comment: I am not sure people have understand the problem. Each `PartialView` is needed by OP to have a form, unless we are already inside one. Thats the issue. A custom helper is needed.

Comment: Can you describe the whole problem as there might exist a better solution. Please give an example of 'something' in the partial view's condition.

Answer (score 0):

`<form>` tag inside another `<form>` is not a valid HTML

Refer [`W3c Spec`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#prohibitions)

Workaround available

http://blog.avirtualhome.com/how-to-create-nested-forms/

Comment: I am not sure you have understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I run into the same problem, and came up with a helper that really solves it.

```
/**
 * Ensure consequent calls to Html.BeginForm are ignored. This is particularly useful
 * on reusable nested components where both a parent and a child begin a form.
 * When nested, the child form shouldn't be printed.
 */
public static class SingleFormExtensions
{
    public static IDisposable BeginSingleForm(this HtmlHelper html)
    {
        return new SingleForm(html);
    }

    public class SingleForm: IDisposable
    {
        // The form, if it was needed
        private MvcForm _form;

        public SingleForm(HtmlHelper html)
        {
            // single per http request
            if (!HttpContext.Current.Items.Contains(typeof(SingleForm).FullName))
            {
                _form = html.BeginForm();
                HttpContext.Current.Items[typeof(SingleForm).FullName] = true; // we need the key added, value is a dummy
            }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            // close the form if it was opened
            if (_form != null)
            {
                _form.EndForm();
                HttpContext.Current.Items.Remove(typeof(SingleForm).FullName);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To use it, include the namespace of the extension and do `@Html.BeginSingleForm(` everywhere you want. Not just inside nested views, but also in the parent.

Points of interest: There is a need to save whether or not the form has opened earlier.  We can't have a static or static per thread variable [ThreadStatic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threadstaticattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), as this might be used by many Asp.Net threads. The only single-threaded and per-http-request place to add a variable is the `HttpContext.Current.Items` dictionary.

There is no limitation to the number of submit buttons. The problem is the nested `form` elements. To avoid having multiple submit buttons you can either hide them using jquery, or extend this helper to automatically add a submit button at the end.